# Generic Sorting function accepts T, but want to ensure T is comparable

Tags: algorithm, sorting, generics, dart

I was doing some Genericizing of a simple MergeSort in Dart.

Just to be a placeholder, i thought a List of `Node` would make a sufficient wrapper to the `List<T>`.  Since T is an object, it doesnt natively have compareTo, <, >, <= etc because it isnt a num or a string.

How do i get these warnings removed.

```
class Node<T> extends Comparable {
  T _value;
  Node(T value){
    _value = value;
  }
  //.....

}

class MergeSort<T>{
  list<Node<T>> _list;

  MergeSort(List<Node<T>> list){
    _list = list;

  }

  List<Node<T>> Sort( List<Node<T>> list ){
    _list = list;
    //.....
  }
}
```

The issue i am getting at is that in the MergeSort, i need to compare nodes, which is fine enough.  I implement `operator ==` etc to handle those cases, or `operator <` for those cases.  I also have, since i extended Comparable, `compareTo` since Strings.

I was not sure how to accommodate for the classes being passed into Node, T, and i didn't know if there was a way to have it `expect` num, string, etc.

full class implementation + a shareable dartpad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/645157fb547da482fc2b

```
class Node<T> extends Comparable{
  T _value;
  Node(T item){
    _value = item;
  }

  T getValue () => _value;

  bool operator ==(other) => identical(this, other);
  bool operator <( other){
    if (other is! T){
      return false;
    }

    //other is of same type, T.
    if (_value < (other as Node<T>).getValue()){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  bool operator <= (other){
    return (this == other) || (this < other);
  }

  int compareTo (other){
    if (this == other){ 
      return 0;  
    }
    if (this < other) { 
      return -1; 
    }
    return 1;  
  }
}
```

Maybe having a Node Wrapper is too much?  I kinda feel like i might be able to strip away the Node class, and just have a List of T, but then the issue would be just pushed into the MergeSort when it comes to comparisons of the list elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
class Node<T extends Comparable>
```

and

```
class MergeSort<T extends Comparable>{
```

but `Comparable` doesn't implement the `>` / `<`. If you want to use these you can create your own superclass that does and require this class to be implemented instead.

Comment: Is this a good way of doing it, given that T could be a String, num, or Object?   Im trying to just generalize the comparison tools as I will want to compare T to other T.

Comment: I guess using `Comparable` would be a good idea. You just can't juse `>` / `<` but instead use the `compareTo(other)` method and then interpret the result `< 0`, `== 0`, `> 0` but that depends on what you actually use it for. For sorting I would definitely go for `Comparable`.

Comment: Was thinking with comparable, numerics would parse to a string automatically, which might not to well for a <, >, ==, stuff, so i might need to look deeper into the resolution a bit more?  Maybe since T extends comparable, that means T would have a compareTo which is defined based on the T.... So it should be good, right>?

Comment: `class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>` is what you want.

Comment: @Jaime and Günter, I have a followup question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670614/adding-the-generic-type-to-a-comparable-type-in-dart