# Adding the generic type to a comparable type in Dart

Tags: dart, generics, comparable

This is a followup question after reading this Q&A:

- [Generic Sorting function accepts T, but want to ensure T is comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122891/generic-sorting-function-accepts-t-but-want-to-ensure-t-is-comparable)

I have a class like so:

```dart
class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable> { ... }
```

so I can create an instance like this:

```dart
final tree = BinarySearchTree<int>();
```

My question is about using `Comparable` vs `Comparable<E>`. When I do this:

```dart
class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable> { ... }
```

then the type defaults to `E extends Comparable<dynamic>`. I normally try to avoid `dynamic`, so in order to be more explicit about the type that is being compared, it seems like I should write it this:

```dart
class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> { ... }
```

But in that case I get an error here:

```dart
final tree = BinarySearchTree<int>();
// 'int' doesn't conform to the bound 'Comparable<int>' of the type parameter 'E'.
// Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Comparable<int>'.
```

This demonstrates my lack of understanding of generics. What am I missing?

Comment: It doesn't work because `int` does not implement `Comparable` directly.  It derives from `num`, and `num` implements `Comparable<num>`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, Since `int` values are also comparable as a `num` subtype, is there any way to keep the generic type and have `int` still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart, a class cannot implement 2 different concrete instances of a generic interface:

```dart
abstract class Foo<T> {}

// error: Foo can only be implemented once
class Bar implements Foo<String>, Foo<int> {}
```

`num` implements `Comparable<num>`, because it would be slightly absurd for the built-in number types to not be comparable. However, since `int` is a subtype of `num` (and therefore inherits `Comparable<num>`, it cannot have `Comparable<int>`.

This leads to the slightly weird consequence that `int` does not implement `Comparable<int>`.

The problem you're facing is that from the language's point of view, there are 2 types involved: the type of the elements being compared, and the type of the elements they are being compared to.

As such, your type will need 2 type parameters:

```dart
class Tree<T extends Comparable<S>, S> {
  T get foo;
}

final intTree = Tree<int, num>();
final foo = intTree.foo;  // returns an int
```

Admittedly, this isn't a super clean solution, but if you're using Dart 2.13 or higher, you can use typedefs to make it a bit nicer:

```dart
typedef IntTree = Tree<int, num>;
typedef RegularTree<T> = Tree<T, T>;

final intTree = IntTree();
final stringTree = RegularTree<String>();

intTree.foo  // is an int
stringTree.foo  // is a String
```

There is another option, which is to just drop some type safety and use `Comparable<dynamic>`, but personally I'd recommend against it. BTW, if you want to avoid accidentally missing type parameters you can disable `implicit-dynamic` as described here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

This will give an error any time the type `dynamic` is inferred from context without the programmer actually typing the word `dynamic`

Comment: Very helpful answer. It was disabling `implicit-dynamic` that largely brought me  here. However, I may enable it in this case since having two types for a tree would be too confusing for the end user of the tree.